# Merge 2 columns of two tables to a third one in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two tables for example

```
1 120
2 100
3 400
4 600
```

and

```
1  150
2  300
3  700
4  350
```

And I want to create a third table with the values

```
120   150
100   300
400   700
600   350
```

Any idea how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
table3 = [table1(:,2) table2(:,2)];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have:

```
a = [1 120
     2 100
     3 400
     4 600];
```

and

```
b = [1  150
     2  300
     3  700
     4  350];
```

Then

```
c = [a(:,2) b(:,2)];
```